# difference among ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction reactreconcileTransaction

Tags: reactjs

In react I saw three transactions in source code. I want to know how they work.

```
ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction 
ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction 
ReactReconcileTransaction
```

After reading it seems to me react is using all of three, in a single click event handler which calls `setState`. Below is the example.

In childComp a clickHandler calls `setState` on child itself, and then calls parent's `handler` which calls `setState` on parent.

My question is in above action, why does react use three transactions? To me it seems only one transaction is enough (like mysql transaction)

ParentComp

```
class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            x: 1
        }
    }

    render() {
        console.log(`parent render, this.state.x=${this.state.x}`)
        return ( 
            <div>
                x in parent: {this.state.x}
                <br />
                <Child x={this.state.x} clickHandler={this.clickHandler} />
            </div>
        );
    }

    clickHandler = () => {
        this.setState({
            x: 2
        })
    }

}
```

ChildComp

```
export default class Child extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            y: 3
        }
    }

    render() {
        console.log(`child render, this.props.x=${this.props.x}, this.state.y=${this.state.y}`)
        return (
            <div>
                x in child: {this.props.x}
                <br />
                    y in child: {this.state.y}
                    <br />
                    <a href="javascript:;" onClick={this.clickHandler}>change</a>
            </div>
        );
    }

    clickHandler = () => {
        this.setState({
            y: 4
        })
        this.props.clickHandler()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the docs state, `setState` is asynchronous, all updates to state are batched and executed, so when you call setState it batches the updates calling `ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction`, now when it has to update the after setState has executed it calls the `ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction` after which it decides which all things it need to update in the DOM thereby executing the `ReactReconcileTransaction`.

So In short

**ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction**:

> Calls the provided function in a `context` within which calls to
>   `setState`  and friends are batched such that components aren't
>   updated unnecessarily.

**ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction:**

> ‘ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction’s wrappers will clear the
>   dirtyComponents array and perform any updates enqueued by mount-ready
>   handlers (i.e., componentDidUpdate)’

**ReactReconcileTransaction**

> Transaction is used during mounting and allows to keep app state safe

Each of these transaction is independently used elsewhere and hence can't be converted into a single one

**[Here](https://bogdan-lyashenko.github.io/Under-the-hood-ReactJS/stack/book/Part-10.html)** is a good article which runs you through the internal of ReactJS